# Is this derivation of the coordinates for uniform accelerated motion in relativity correct?

Tags: relativity

I was trying to derive coordinates for uniform accelerated motion (in the theory of relativity).  I know there is a derivation that goes like this:

Given a four-velocity $a^{\mu}$ we impose that this acceleration is constant and spacelike:
$$a_{\mu} a^{\mu} = -g^2 $$
where $g$ is a positive constant.
From the definition of four-velocity we also know that
$$a^{\mu} = \frac{d u^{\mu}}{d \tau} = \frac{d^2 x^{\mu}}{d \tau^2} $$
Then we replace this definition of four-acceleration in the first equation (lets assume just two dimensions to simplify):
$$ \frac{d^2 x^0}{d \tau^2} - \frac{d^2 x^1}{d \tau^2} = -g^2 $$
Then a solution can be guessed from this equation. The solution has the form
$$x^0 (\tau) = a^{-1} sinh(a \tau) $$
$$x^1 (\tau) = a^{-1} cosh(a \tau) $$
I understand perfectly this derivation. Yet I tried derivating in another way but my answer does not match the one given before. My derivation goes like this:
Although there is accelerating motion, the observer is in a flat space time, thus we have
$$dt^2 - dx^2 = dt \otimes dt -  dx \otimes dx = d\tau \otimes d \tau $$
Where $\tau$ is the proper time of the moving observer.
The four velocity of this moving observer is 
$$ X = \frac{\partial }{\partial \tau} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial \tau} \frac{\partial }{\partial x} +  \frac{\partial t}{\partial \tau} \frac{\partial }{\partial t}$$
Inserting $X \otimes X $ into $ dt \otimes dt -  dx \otimes dx = d\tau \otimes d \tau $ we obtain
$$(\frac{d t}{d \tau})^2 - (\frac{d x}{d \tau})^2 = 1 $$
Now we know that since the moving observer has a constant acceleration then
$$\frac{d^2 x}{d t^2} = a $$ 
where $a$ is a positive constant. If at time $t=0$ the moving observer has $0$ velocity then $x(t) = a t^2 + c$. Then
$$\frac{d x}{d\tau} = 2 a t \frac{d t}{d \tau} $$
Replacing this in equation $(\frac{d t}{d \tau})^2 - (\frac{d x}{d \tau})^2 = 1 $ we have
$$1 = (\frac{d t}{d \tau})^2 - 4 a^2 t^2 (\frac{d t}{d \tau})^2 $$
Thus,
$$\frac{d \tau}{d t} = \sqrt{1-4a^2t^2} $$ 
If I integrate this I don't obtain anything near the solution for the problem. Am I making some mistake in this derivation? is there any way to fix it so that it gives the correct solution?

Comment: Why do you have $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = a$?  This isn't consistent with SR.  It's OK to stipulate that the moving observer has constant *proper* acceleration but not constant *coordinate* acceleration as you've done

Comment: This may be asking too much, but why is it not consistent with SR? $x$ and $y$ are the coordinates given by an observer to an accelerating object, wouldn't he see the accelerating object with a constant acceleration $a$?

Comment: Pam, for the simplest case where the force is always parallel to the velocity, it's straightforward to derive the following relationship between the proper acceleration $\alpha$ (the acceleration measured by an accelerometer attached to the object) and the coordinate acceleration $a$ as measured by an inertial observer:
$$\alpha = \gamma^3_v a$$
See that, for constant proper acceleration, the coordinate acceleration goes to zero as the object's speed approaches $c$. But, if one fixes $a$, the object's speed can reach and exceed $c$ and $\alpha$ goes to $\infty$ and then becomes imaginary.

Comment: Thank you @AlfredCentauri this has cleared up things for me!

Comment: Just another question to be sure: So the $a$ in my derivation corresponds to coordinate acceleration and  the $a$ (or $g$) in the first derivation is the proper acceleration. If I understand correctly then, if in my derivation I somehow transformed the coordinate acceleration $a$ into the  proper acceleration then I should obtain the same answer, is this correct?